# problem with dropdownlist in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to work with an HTML.DropDownList in MVC and am not getting the expected return values.  Here is my implementation for the selectList to bind to the drop down -

```
IEnumerable<status> stat = _provider.GetAllStatuses();
Statuses = new SelectList(stat.ToList(), "id", "name", i.status.id);
```

And here is my view -

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Status",Model.Statuses) %>
```

I am getting an error when trying to run updatemodel in my controller.  I then tried to individually set each object.  It turns out that I am not getting a single int from the formvalue as I would expect to.  Instead, I am getting a value like "5,10,2,3".  I think this is coming from how I set up my selectlist, but I'm not exactly sure.  Can anyone see an error in the way I am setting up this dd?

Thanks for any help, and let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the signature of the post method look like?  It (or the model) should have a Status property that's defined as an int.  I suspect that you've got more code than you're showing us that is listing all the potential statuses on the page (hidden fields?) and that's what you are seeing posted back as an array of ints.

It should look something like:

```
 public ActionResult PostAction( int status, .... )
 {
   ... status will contain the selected value from the dropdown ...
 }
```

Comment: I found the issue - I have multiple dd lists and I accidentally had some labeled the same as my status box.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it:

```
var stat = _provider.GetAllStatuses(); 
myViewDataObject.Statuses = new SelectList(stat, "id", "name", i.status.id);
```

stat is an `IEnumerable`.  Statuses is of type `SelectList`.  You don't need `ToList()` if you are returning an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` from your provider.

My view inherits from

```
System.Web.Mvc.Viewpage<MyProject.Models.MyViewDataClass>
```

which looks like this:

```
class MyViewDataClass
{
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, I am accepting a FormsCollection object, and using the model binder to update it:

```
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection collection)
{
   var myViewDataObject = new MyViewDataClass();
   UpdateModel(myViewDataObject);
}
```

More info at http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help - that is very similar to how I was set up. It turned out to be an error in my aspx page.